# What is a "reducer" in the context of React?

Tags: reactjs

I know how to use the `useReducer` hook in React, but I don't understand why they are called "reducers".

The word "reduce" generally means "make smaller or less in amount". But it's not clear to me why the React concept of a reducer has this name.

What is the reasoning behind calling this function a "reducer" in React? Some insight into the history and meaning behind this terminology would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The documentation for a `reducer` (which is the result of `useReducer`) from https://react.dev/learn/extracting-state-logic-into-a-reducer says `Components with many state updates spread across many event handlers can get overwhelming. For these cases, you can consolidate all the state update logic outside your component in a single function, called a reducer.`. So the name "reducer" actually makes sense because you reduce the update logic from several functions into one consolidated one.

Comment: see [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), [fold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)) then there is "map/reduce" to give you a few directions

Answer (score 1):

Wiktionary defines a [reducer](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reducer) as follows:

> A function that takes state and action as arguments and returns the next state of the app.

Which is exactly what React `useReducer` hook takes as an argument.

This concept is not specific to React or even Javascript.

Another example of function that takes a reducer as an argument is the [Array.reduce method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3];
const sum = array.reduce((accumulator, current) => accumulator + current, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's called like that is because `useReducer` is the modern alternative to Redux. And in Redux they are called reducers: https://redux.js.org/introduction/core-concepts